# String.at() returning funky numbers

Tags: c++

when I am trying to run this snippet of code I am getting some malfunctions I have not been able to pinpoint the cause of. The first two "cout" lines display the numbers 7 and 3, however, the last "cout" line displays numbers ranging from 50-60 usually (At the moment when I run it I get 55 and 51, which seems to somehow correlate a bit with the numbers I am trying to read). As far as I can tell from some googling and the books I have at hand this should be valid, but there's obviously something I am missing. Thank you for your time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string text = "73";
    int one=0, two=0;

    cout << text.at(0) << endl;
    cout << text.at(1) << endl;
    one = text.at(0);
    two = text.at(1);
    cout << one << endl << two << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the program functions correctly: `text.at()` returns a `char`, which you implicitly convert to an `int`. Then you print the value of that int, which are respectively 55 for "7" and 51 for "3" (look [here](http://www.asciitable.com/)).

Comment: @Flyphe it's not an error. It's printing the integer representation of the character.

Comment: @kenny ah ok. I just figured since char and int are not the same it should maybe give a conversion error.

Comment: It's doing what you told it to do, not what you wanted it to do.  That's what computers do.  Get used to it.

Comment: @PaulToblin exactly. It's never the computer's fault. How I wish all users understood that.

Comment: @PaulTomblin damn puters are a rigid and anal bunch...sometimes more than engineers behind them! :0